# I have 3 USB-C devices, a computer, a tablet and a phone. They all have different chargers but the same port. What happens if I plug in the wrong one?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, usb-c

Each of my USB-C enabled devices charge via the plug.
Each came with a USB-C chargerbut my phone does not need much power
so the power adapter is small.

My laptop needs a lot of power and its charger is more powerful.

What happens if I mess up and I plug my phone in the PC charger? 
Does the phone blow up?

And what happens if I try to charge my PC with my phone charger will it catch fire?

Answer (score 2):

Your devices will charge and no damage will occur.

If you plug a charger in which has a lower current rating the devices will charge slower.

If you plug a charger in which has a higher current rating the devices will charge at their designated speed.

USB-C negotiates the desired power delivery profile, starting off at 5 volts, 2 amps.

Comment: The last sentence is highly inaccurate. USB-C "negotiates" only if the port implements Power Delivery protocol. Not all Type-C ports have it. As a matter of fact, very few as of today. A standard Type-C provider (charger or host port) ADVERTISE their capability my means of value of a simple pull-up resistor on a CC pin, and the standard set has three options, default 500/900 mA, 1.5 A, and 3 A. The concept of "power delivery profile" is from PD specifications, which are independent of Type-C connector specification.

Answer (score 1):

Any pair of USB-C device and charger will start at normal-level charging, and some higher-power chargers will negotiate higher-level charging if the device can handle it.  It's probably safe, but will be slower charging.